# AS3 - Remove a Specific Instance of a MovieClip with removeChild() Function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a Flash game for an assignment.  It's a pretty standard missile defense-type game, with a rotating missile launcher in the center firing up at passing bombers above.  The missiles and bombers are functioning correctly by themselves, but I'm running into a problem when I try to get the two to interact.  Specifically, when a missile hits a bomber, I want the specific instances of that missile and that bomber to be removed from the screen and have their respective event listeners removed, but everything I've tried has failed and I can't seem to figure out just how to do it.

Here are the Main, Bomber, and Missile classes I'm working with:

**The Main Class:**

```
    package {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public var background:Background;
        public var launcher:Launcher;
        public var mount:Mount;
        public var missile:Missile;
        public var salvo:Array = [];
        public var bomber:Bomber;
        public var squadron:Array = [];



        /* 
         * This function sets up the permanent items (items that remain on-stage for
         * the duration of the game) and adds event listeners that call functions to
         * add non-permanent items to the stage
         */

        public function Main() {

            // Add background to the stage
            background = new Background(stage);
            stage.addChild(background);
            stage.setChildIndex(background, 0);

            // Add the rotating launcher to the stage
            launcher = new Launcher(stage);
            stage.addChild(launcher);
            stage.setChildIndex(launcher, 1);

            // Add the static mount to the stage (on top of launcher)
            mount = new Mount(stage);
            stage.addChild(mount);
            stage.setChildIndex(mount, 2);

            // Call loop() every new frame
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

            // Call fire() every time the mouse is clicked
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fire);
        }



        /*
         * This function runs every time the program enters a new frame, or 60 times
         * every second.  Each time this function runs, it tries to add a new Bomber
         * to the squadron array and checks to see if there are any Missiles or
         * Bombers currently in their respective arrays (and if so, calls a function
         * to make them move).
         */

        public function loop(evt:Event) {

            // If the random number generated by Math.random() is less than
            // waveLimiter, create a new Bomber and add it to the squadron array.
            if(Math.random() < 0.02 /* Change this number to change how fast bombers spawn */) {
                bomber = new Bomber(stage);
                bomber.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeBomber); // If the Bomber is removed from the stage, call removeBomber() to remove its event handler.
                squadron.push(bomber);
                stage.addChild(bomber);
                stage.setChildIndex(bomber, 1);
            }

            // Check to see if there is at least one missile in the salvo array, and
            // if so, call Missile.velocity() to make it move.
            if(salvo.length > 0) {
                for(var i:int = salvo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    salvo[i].velocity();
                }
            }

            // Check to see if there is at least one bomber in the squadron array,
            // and if so, call Bomber.fly() to make it move.
            if(squadron.length > 0) {
                for(var j:int = squadron.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    squadron[j].fly();
                }
            }
        }



        /*
         * This function checks for a mouse click, and if it detects one, creates a 
         * new Missile and adds it to the salvo array.
         */

        public function fire(evt:MouseEvent) {

            missile = new Missile(stage, launcher.rotation);
            missile.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeMissile); // If the Missile is removed from the stage, call removeMissile() to remove its event handler. 
            salvo.push(missile);
            stage.addChild(missile);
            stage.setChildIndex(missile, 1);
        }



        /*
         * This function removes the EVENT LISTENER for the current Missile instance.
         * It does not remove the Missile itself from the stage.
         */

        public function removeMissile(evt:Event):void {
            evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeMissile);
            salvo.splice(salvo.indexOf(evt.currentTarget), 1);
        }



        /*
         * This function removes the EVENT LISTENER for the current Bomber instance.
         * It does not remove the Bomber itself from the stage.
         */

        public function removeBomber(evt:Event) {
            evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeBomber);
            squadron.splice(squadron.indexOf(evt.currentTarget), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**The Bomber class:**

```
    package  {

    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Bomber extends MovieClip {

        var stageInstance:Stage;
        var randomNumber:Number = Math.round(Math.random() * 1);

        public function Bomber(stageInstance:Stage):void {

            this.stageInstance = stageInstance;
            if(randomNumber == 1) {
                x = -39;
                y = (Math.random() * 120) + 30;
            }

            else if(randomNumber == 0) {
                scaleX *= -1;
                x = 679;
                y = (Math.random() * 120) + 30;
            }
        }

        public function fly():void {

            if(randomNumber == 1) {
                x = x + 4;
            }

            else if(randomNumber == 0) {
                x = x - 4;
            }

            if(x > 680 || x < -40) {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The Missile Class:**

```
package {

    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Missile extends MovieClip {

        var stageInstance:Stage;
        var velocityX:Number;
        var velocityY:Number;
        var speed:Number = 10;
        var rotationRadians:Number;
        var rotationDegrees:Number;

        public function Missile(stageInstance:Stage, rotationDegrees:Number):void {
            this.stageInstance = stageInstance;
            x = 320;
            y = 363;
            rotation = rotationDegrees;
            rotationRadians = rotationDegrees * Math.PI / 180;
        }

        public function velocity():void {
            velocityX = Math.cos(rotationRadians) * speed;
            velocityY = Math.sin(rotationRadians) * speed;

            x += velocityX;
            y += velocityY;

            if(x > 640 || x < 0 || y > 480 || y < 0) {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

In the Main Class, I've tried adding something like this:

```
if(squadron.length > 0) {
    for(var j:int = squadron.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        squadron[j].fly();

        if(salvo.length > 0) {
            if(missile.hitTestObject(squadron[j])) {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But no luck.  I've also tried using a trace statement, and it doesn't even give me an output, which leads me to think it's not even detecting collision at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I added a few more details.

`this` represents the object on which the function is called. So 
`this.parent.removeChild(this);` makes no sense when it is written in the main class. 
When you write it in the Missile Class, `this` is the Missile instance, and `this.parent` is the stage.

Try replacing it with: `stage.removeChild(missile)`, in the last sample of code you posted, and call removeMissile() just after.

Comment: Okay, that's running without any errors, but it's not actually removing the missiles.  As I suspected, it seems that it's not even registering the hit at all, and unfortunately, I have no idea why.

Comment: hm, if you can't figure out logically what's going on or have trouble tracing it, try adding in traces at each of your blocks to see where the issue is. One at the start, then another for the first if statement, another for the loop, another for the next if statement, and another in the hit test if statement. Then run it and see what is printed (and not printed) to see where it stops.

Comment: This gets stranger and stranger.  I've determined that it IS registering the hit, but only under VERY specific circumstances.  It only registers when I begin firing before any bombers have appeared (generating a #2007 error in the process), and then only if the missiles hit the first bomber that appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use stage.removeChild instead this.parent.removeChild(this);

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have many problems in your code. First of all, you don't need to work with Stage. You can work with your main container `Main`. When you add object to the display list, don't do after `setChildIndex`. In your code It doesn't have any sense. Also you don't need any length conditions. And create light objects by extending Sprite, not MovieClip.

Code for your loop, for missiles:

```
private function loop(e: Event):void {

    //...not full listing

    var i:uint, j:uint, salvos:uint = salvo.length, bombers:uint = squadron.length, missile:Missle, bomber:Bomber;
    var disposeMissiles:Array = [];
    var disposeBombers:Array = [];

    //Rendering missiles
    for (i = 0; i < salvos; ++i) {
        missile = salvo[i];
        missile.valocity();

        for (j = 0; j < bombers; ++j) {
            bomber = squadron[j];

            if (!bomber.isHitted() && missile.hitTestObject(bomber)) {
                //Dispose both missile and bomber
                bomber.setHitted = true;
                disposeMissiles.push(missile);
                disposeBombers.push(bomber);
            }
        }
    }

    //Clear lists and display list
    disposeObjects(disposeMissiles, salvo);
    disposeObjects(disposeBombers, squadron);
}

private function disposeObjects(objects:Array, from:Array):void {
    //Create interface for both missiles and bombers, like IGameActor
    var i:uint, len:uint = objects.length, objectToRemove:IGameActor;

    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        objectToRemove = objects[i];
        //Remove from the display list, in your design Parent is Stage
        this.stage.removeChild(DisplayObject(objectToRemove));
        //Release memory, links, event listeners
        objectToRemove.dispose();
        //Try manage also indexes, splice is slow operation
        from.splice(from.indexOf(objectToRemove), 1);
    }
}
```